# Checking if nullable ulong HasValue in C#

Tags: c#

```
public static string getBucket(ulong? ItemValue)
{            
    if!(ItemValue.HasValue)
    {
    return String.Empty;
    }    
}
```

Is this a viable way to check if a variable of data type ulong does not contain a value.

Comment: If you typed your code into an editor it would tell you that there are at least two problems with it.  Instead of asking StackOverflow to check your work, **type it into an editor**.

Comment: Also, [read the documentation!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094(v=vs.110).aspx). "Gets a value indicating whether the current Nullable<T> object has a valid value of its underlying type."

Answer (score 1):

`ulong` and `ulong?` are two different things.

**`ulong`** (without the `?`) is a value type. It **always** has a value, and cannot exist without one. If you declare a `ulong` and forget to the assign anything to it, the value will match `default(ulong)`, [which is 0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table).

**`ulong?`** (with the `?`) is also a value type, but it's a shorthand for the ulong specialization of the generic `Nullable<T>` structure. You **do** use the `HasValue` property to check whether or not it has a value.

What you should **NOT** do is return a string when you're dealing with a number. Additionally, the method fails to return a value when the `if()` fails and the `!` must go *inside* the parentheses for the `if()` condition. This is basic stuff, even for beginners; if you're having trouble with that, I'm sorry to say you're gonna have a hard time as a programmer.

Comment: The method is also missing a second  `return` statement. I disagree on your strings and numbers stayement. The method is called GetBucket, not GetNumber. Business logic may dictate an empty string for a bucket name in that case whereas the rest of the method (the missing parts) might potentially generate a string based on that number.